# How to check if an array contains another array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I would have a rather simple question today. We have the following resource:

```
$a = array(1 => 5, 2 => 3, 3 => 13, 9 => array('test'), 4 => 32, 5 => 33);
```

How is it actually possible to find out if array "a" has an array element in it and return the key if there is one (or more)?

Comment: You can probably use [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/in_array)

Comment: Is the `array_diff()` the function you are looking for?

Comment: I would probably loop through it and test with is_array - capture the key, and return the keys when you're done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
function look_for_array(array $test_var) {
  foreach ($test_var as $key => $el) {
    if (is_array($el)) {
      return $key;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

It's rather trivial to convert this function into collecting all such keys:

```
function look_for_all_arrays(array $test_var) {
  $keys = [];
  foreach ($test_var as $key => $el) {
    if (is_array($el)) {
      $keys[] = $key;
    }
  }
  return $keys;
}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/103453).

Comment: Yes, I've tried the same, but this way, I will receive `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() `, because it's in the wrong format for the array one. I know I can just ignore it with `@` but is there any other way around it?

Comment: Note that `array` typehint in the function's parameter. If you're not sure whether or not `$test_var` is an array, you should check it as well (with `is_array`) - but that probably means something else is wrong in your code.

Comment: Thank you I've found the issue in my code. The problem was that I've typed wrong some elements in the array actually. Thank you for the answer, I must by very tired that I've checked it multiple times and didn't see an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $array = array(1 => 5, 2 => 3, 3 => 13, 9 => array('test'), 4 => 32, 5 => 33);
 foreach($array as $key => $value){
   if(is_Array($value)){
      echo $value[key($value)];
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in different way.

```
$a = array(1 => 5, 2 => 3, 3 => 13, 9 => array('test'), 4 => 32, 5 => 33);

foreach ( $a as $aas  ):

        if(is_array($aas)){
            foreach ($aas as $key => $value):
                echo " (child array is this $key : $value)";
        endforeach;
        }else{
                echo " Value of array a = $aas : ";


        }
  endforeach;
```

output is like :

```
  Value of array a = 5 : Value of array a = 3 :
 Value of array a = 13 : (child array is this 0 :
 test) Value of array a = 32 : Value of array a = 33 :
```